# UITextView always starting in the middle for iMessages Apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have tried all the solutions posted on the web and nothing seems to be working. For some weird reason (BUG) the UITextView always starts in the middle of the screen.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.firstTextView.contentOffset.y = -self.firstTextView.contentInset.top
        }

        //self.firstTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
    }
```

Also none of these worked:

```
  // self.firstTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7.0,0.0,0,0.0);

//        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 2)) {
//            
//            print("dispatched")
//            
//            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
//            
//            self.firstTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
//        }

        //self.firstTextView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)), animated: false)


        //self.firstTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
        //self.firstTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
        //self.firstTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 1))
```

The above code did not work!

[image]

UPDATE: I don't see any control option. This is an iPhone App.

[image]

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using? My solution was with XCode 8.0

Comment: Xcode 8.0. I m using a UITextView. I believe you are using UITextField. Totally different things!

Comment: whoops. My mistake!

Comment: How did you make multi line textfield in storyboard?

Comment: currently it's not, it just runs on to the right.

Comment: although, My new UITextView is aligned to the top by default

Comment: The screenshot you posted has UITextField in multiple lines.

Comment: No, it is single line. it is/was just aligned to the top/center of its bounds.

Comment: This question should not have been downvoted.  I'm having this exact same problem and it's definitely a legitimate question.